# Delaying a logic level by some ms

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, timer

I have a sub-module in a design that has it's own regulator, i want to use its enable pin driven by an MCU output to also toggle some other IC, say 10ms after the EN has transitioned.

I know i can just use two digital pins, but is there a way using an rc circuit or capacitor to do this in hardware?

Of course the alternative is to use a supervisor, but it'll be unnecessary if there's a cheaper way.

Update: The IC that needs to be enabled with some lag is active-low, and the purpose of the lag is to wait until the output of the regulator is at a stable Vcc.

One of [these](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11184d.pdf) would be the most correct way, but the enable pin is coming from an MCU with its own brown out detector so some generous lag (not a time critical system) should suffice.

Edit 2: [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dir9001.pdf) is the IC.

Comment: A one shot would do the trick. Something like the 74xx121/2/3 might work.

Comment: If Threshold is Vcc/2 +/-25% over temp and RC=T at 63%  you can choose 15ms=RC adding a load of series 15k and 1uF shunt ... good for 33% accuracy or so

Comment: As long as your IC can tolerate a slow rise rate on its input select RC. Otherwise, additionally add a schmitt trigger after RC before IC input pin.

Comment: Though using a free GPIO pin you already have is pretty cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've added an update as I seem to have missed out some information. Having said that, if @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 's solution wouldn't be applicable given the update, then i could just go with a free GPIO.

Comment: The reset supervisor you linked is for a system that is enabled active-high (reset active-low).

Comment: You want a UVP and POR both. then what will you do when it is running and UVP occurs.  (Reset?)  or send battery status?  Do you want enable or Reset_

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the same wire that connects to the EN to the regulator, connects to the RESET' of the second IC. 

I am connecting to RESET', and I want the second IC to sleep for some time until the wire connecting to the regulators EN pin has been HIGH for some duration. Does that make sense?

Comment: You want the reset to come out when the power is good on the regulator, so you create a power-good on its output, not a delay on the enable signal. Unless you know 100% sure nothing in the world can ever happen, you want to base it off the supply voltage. Many chips that require stable supply to avoid problems have an optional built in Brown-Out system with delays in some cases, but you can make one yourself as well. Some DC/DC chips or modules even just have a Power-Good output that goes high (or low) when the output is within 10% of the set-point.

Comment: @Asmyldof I may have misunderstood you, but it's not the enable signal that delays, it's a branch off of the enable signal that blocks the high signal for some time, whilst the enable signal itself which is already high has already enabled the regulator. Edit: i have seen the MCP120T-300 which would do the job, just wondered if there's a passive method to do this.

Comment: "The IC that needs to be enabled with some lag is active-low...I've added an update as I seem to have missed out some information." - important information is still missing. What is the second IC?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem. What's the circuit, and what problem are you running into?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Apologies, have added the IC in the second edit inside the question.

Comment: @Polynomial I've made a circuit that inputs various audio sources, and passes one through a single output. This addition to the circuit i'm working on involves the IC i've linked and a PCM5102 as it's DAC to additionally cater for a digital audio channel via SPDIF. 

The problem is, i want the IC i linked to come out of a reset state some time after its regulator has been enabled, and i wanted to know if it's possible with passive components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DIR9001's /RST line is a Schmitt-trigger input with nominal 51kΩ pullup. Therefore a reliable reset delay should be obtainable by simply wiring a capacitor to Ground.

To control it from your MCU you either need an Open Drain output, or a diode to isolate the capacitor from the high output (which will also isolate it from anything else the MCU might be driving).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIJeO6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the MCU output is low it holds the capacitor voltage down to ~0.5V (voltage drop across the silicon diode). When the output goes high it allows the capacitor to charge exponentially through the pullup resistor. Reset will be removed when it reaches 2.0V.

The formula for the required capacitance is:- $$C = - \frac{t}{R \times ln(\frac{V_s-V_c}{V_s})} $$

where \$V_s\$ is the supply voltage and \$V_c\$ is the capacitor voltage at time \$t\$. Since the diode produces an offset of ~0.5V the effective charging voltages are 3.3 - 0.5 = 2.8V and 2.0 - 0.5 = 1.5V. Plugging those numbers into the formula we get C1 = ~260nF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and patience. 

Looking at section 8.3.2 on page 12, realising I can get away with a smaller capacitor if I calculate for a smaller time, since a minimum of 100ns is required after reset' has reached 2.7V. And I'm thinking a Schottky diode might give a little more room/tolerance between the reset voltage and the effective charging voltage. 

Would my calculations for C at 12nF be right with:
V_drop = 0.25V
t =  1ms
V_s = 3.25V
(reset removed at voltage 2.7V) so effective charging voltages = 3V and 2.45V

Comment: Effective charging voltages with 0.25V Schottky diode would be 3.0-0.25=3.05V and 2-0.25=1.75V (Schmitt trigger voltage is fixed at 2.0V so Vs-Vc is still 3.3-2.0=1.3V). Theoretical capacitance for 1ms is 23nF.

Comment: Ah, the value for the schmitt trigger threw me then, still no problem. I've used this design in my PCB, thanks :)